# Using DNS to Point a Domain to a Specific Page?

Tags: dns, forwarding

I know this question seems pretty straight-forward, but I'm having a hard time pulling up any answers on Google / Other Forums.

A client has a few domains parked on Network Solutions - not attached to any hosting account. I'm planning to point one of the recently purchased domains to a sub-directory of our main site (hosted elsewhere) - as part of a special promotion that's running.

However, Network Solutions now charges for Web Forwarding. In hopes of avoiding an additional charge I thought I'd use the DNS settings to point the IP to the site - but that just takes the user to the main website's home-page --- and not the specific sub-directory I need it to.

Since the domains are just parked - and not associated with a hosting account, I don't have access to a .htaccess file to deal with 301 forwarding or anything there.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault? I don't see a programming question (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I figured it was a general web development question - I apologize if its not posted in the right area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just point the DNS to your server and set up vhosts for each of the new domains. Then, drop in a one-line JS or PHP index file (or mod_rewrite rule) to redirect to the desired page on your main site.

Comment: The main site is hosted in a shared hosting environment - I haven't ever tried to set up a vhost on a shared host. Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on the host. Another option is to use a scripting language like PHP and insert a hook into the index page that looks at the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable. For example: if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'newdomain.com') { header('Location: ...'); exit; }

Comment: I didn't think about that - that will work perfectly for what I need. I'll go test that out now. Thank you.